# Functional programming in C++17

Tags: c++

Some of the functional programming (FP) paradigm will be added in C++17. This code folds the product function over the input values, to print the product of all the numbers.

```
template<typename... T>
auto fold_mul(T... t){
    return (t * ...);
}
```

usage

```
cout << fold_mul(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) << "\n";
```

Does anyone know if there are plans to expand this *higher order functions* and *no side-effects* like a fully featured FP language?

Comment: are you asking if functions such as this will be added to the standard library?

Comment: Are you talking about compile time or run time evaluation of your functional programming? In the case above I'd guess reasonable compilers will evaluate that during compile time. That isn't new with C++17 (except the `auto` return value).

Comment: Just because something looks like something you know from functional programming doesn't mean that's what it is or why it is being added. Being able to expand parameter packs through expressions like this is not a feature that was added for the sake of being more functional.

Comment: This will not be added to C++17 AFAIK. It was part of Concepts and I highly doubt they will get in.

Comment: @chris: Fold expressions are not part of concepts. And they were already voted into C++17 (though they are undergoing modifications).

Comment: @NicolBolas, My mistake. I tied them more closely because fold expressions were primarily introduced to support Concepts. It's good to see them going in separately.

Comment: You can fake this with tuples, you just need to put `...` in a tuple and define the operators you'd like (in a templated manner for both sides).

Comment: Pattern matching from FP [this] (https://isocpp.org/blog/2016/07/cppcon-2015-simple-extensible-pattern-matching-in-cpp14-john-r.-bandela)